# Convert joda DateTime to java.time.LocalDate

Tags: datetime

I would have one just simple question: How to convert from joda DateTime to LocalDate?

I have tried it like this but with no success:

```
final LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.ofEpochDay(start.getMillis());
```

Comment: LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(start.getYear(), start.getMonthOfYear(), start.getDayOfMonth());
            LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.of(end.getYear(), end.getMonthOfYear(), end.getDayOfMonth()); does it

Answer (score 25):

```java
public class DateUtils {
    
    /**
     * Convert {@link java.time.LocalDate} to {@link org.joda.time.DateTime}
     */
    public DateTime toDateTime(LocalDate localDate) {
        return new DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC).withDate(
            localDate.getYear(), localDate.getMonthValue(), localDate.getDayOfMonth()
        ).withTime(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    
    /**
     * Convert {@link org.joda.time.DateTime} to {@link java.time.LocalDate}
     */
    public LocalDate toLocalDate(DateTime dateTime) {
        DateTime dateTimeUtc = dateTime.withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC);
        return LocalDate.of(dateTimeUtc.getYear(), dateTimeUtc.getMonthOfYear(), dateTimeUtc.getDayOfMonth());
    }
}
```

Comment: .withTime(0, 0, 0, 0) can be replaced by .withTimeAtStartOfDay()

Comment: Seems this answer should be correct? Maybe the original question was asked too long ago.

Comment: Why this code converts DateTime to UTC? Author didn't ask for that.

Answer (score -3):

```
    LocalDateTime demoDateTime = Instant.ofEpochMilli(DateTime.now().getMillis())
            .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
            .toLocalDateTime();
    demoDateTime.toLocalDate();
    demoDateTime.toLocalTime();
```

use mili seconds to convert.